# Is there any way I can use strtof() to convert a "negative number?"

Tags: c, string

I am trying to write a function to convert a string to mathematical operation.

```
int RPN_Evaluate(char * rpn_string, double * result)
{
   struct Stack calculate = {};
   char *token;
   char *endptr;
   double x,y;

   token = strtok(rpn_string, " ");
    while (token != NULL) {
        *number = strtof(token, &endptr);
        if (*token == '+') {
            StackPop(&calculate, &y);
            StackPop(&calculate, &x);
            result_operation = x + y;
            StackPush(&calculate, result_operation);
        } else if (*token == '-') {
            StackPop(&calculate, &y);
            StackPop(&calculate, &x);
            result_operation = x - y;
            StackPush(&calculate, result_operation);
        }else if (*endptr != NULL) {
            return RPN_ERROR_INVALID_TOKEN;
        } else if (*endptr == NULL) { 
            StackPush(&calculate, *number);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }

    StackPop(&calculate, result);
    return RPN_NO_ERROR;
}
```

If I pass in "1 1 +" , it works just fine. However, I encounter issue when I pass in "2 -1 +"
Is there any way I can use strtof() to convert "-1" to -1? strtof() doesn't seem to do that automatically.

Comment: [`strtof("-1", ...)` works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/N2Nm7c). I suggest you take some time with a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: `strtof` definitely can handle a negative number. See [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/). Your problem is that you're parsing the leading `-` of your `-1` as a `-` operator; your `if/else` construct is wrong.

Comment: your question (and posted function prototype) indicates the result is to be a `double`,  So rather than `*number = strtof(token, &endptr);`  suggest: `*number = strtod(token, &endptr);`  However, where is `number` declared and where is `result_operation` declared and where are the functions: `StackPush()` and `StackPop()` declared?